# Android - How to Draw Graphics on SurfaceView

Tags: android, android-layout, opengl-es

[image: Draw something on top surface view]

Like the picture above.
What I want to do is to make an appearance as above (which is inside the red box).
How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add your SurfaceView to a RelativeLayout, create the red box in a xml, and place it inside your RelativeLayout, overlapping the SurfaceView!

Or you can use inside your the Canvas drawing method canvas.drawText for the values, canvas.drawRect for the white rectangle, and canvas.drawPoints for the rest.

You can read more in the [canvas reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html) page.